# Passing block text to md-sizenav

Tags: angularjs, node.js, pug

I have the following jade template:

```
extend default

block content
  .container(layout='row', flex='')
  md-sidenav.lightblue(md-is-locked-open='true')
    p.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pri tacimates salutatus forensibus ea. Sit ceteros hendrerit
      consequuntur an, dicta tibique eu vis. Habeo impetus comprehensam te nam, in sit feugait
      principes. Cibo possit oblique qui cu, aperiri vivendum sed ne. Minim repudiare ne cum,
      ex graeco quodsi ius.
```

This extends a default.jade, which is referenced here:

```
.main-content
        md-toolbar
            h1 Angular Material Starter!
        block content
```

However, I can't seem to pass in a block of text to `md-sidenav.` -- it only accepts strings on the same line. Is there a way I can use the block of text, while still maintaining the cleanliness of the jade template?

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was to just make use of the jade `|`:

```
block content
  .container(layout='row', flex='')
  md-sidenav.lightblue(md-is-locked-open='true')
    p.
    | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pri tacimates salutatus forensibus ea. Sit ceteros hendrerit
    |  consequuntur an, dicta tibique eu vis. Habeo impetus comprehensam te nam, in sit feugait
    |  principes. Cibo possit oblique qui cu, aperiri vivendum sed ne. Minim repudiare ne cum,
    | ex graeco quodsi ius.
```